# Integración de código para Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

necesito unir 2 códigos; soy nuevo en esto de Arduino pero solo se hacer proyectos básicos por así decirlo. Les Agradecería mucho que me ayuden

El primer codigo es para encender un led con la voz mediante Bluethoon:

```
String mensaje;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);//Iniciando comunicación Serial a 9600 baudios
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);//declarando pin 13 como salida
}
void loop(){
  while(Serial.available()){//Confirmando que la comunicación Serial esté disponible para hacer la lectura del mensaje
    delay(10);//para dar estabilidad al programa
    char c = Serial.read();//c almacena la lectura de la comunicación serial
    mensaje += c; //sumando el contenido de la variable c en la variable mensaje
  }
  if(mensaje.length()>0){//verificando que la variable mensaje no esté vacía
    if(mensaje=="*encender"){digitalWrite(13,HIGH);}//interpretando mensaje
    else if (mensaje=="*Apagar"){digitalWrite(13,LOW);}//y ejecutando instrucciones
  }
  mensaje="";//reseteando variable 
}
```

EL SEGUNDO ES PARA MOVER 4 SERVOMOTORES CON BLUETHOON:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> // TX RX software library for bluetooth
 #include <Servo.h> // servo library 
Servo myservo1, myservo2, myservo3, myservo4; // servo name
int bluetoothTx = 10; // bluetooth tx to 10 pin
int bluetoothRx = 11; // bluetooth rx to 11 pin
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);
void setup()
{
  myservo1.attach(3); // attach servo signal wire to pin 9
  myservo2.attach(5);
  myservo3.attach(6);
  myservo4.attach(9);
  //Setup usb serial connection to computer
  Serial.begin(9600);
//Setup Bluetooth serial connection to android
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
  //Read from bluetooth and write to usb serial
  if(bluetooth.available()>= 2 )
  {
    unsigned int servopos = bluetooth.read();
    unsigned int servopos1 = bluetooth.read();
    unsigned int realservo = (servopos1 *256) + servopos;
    Serial.println(realservo);
if (realservo >= 1000 && realservo <1180) {
      int servo1 = realservo;
      servo1 = map(servo1, 1000, 1180, 0, 180);
      myservo1.write(servo1);
      Serial.println("Servo 1 ON");
      delay(10);
    }
    if (realservo >= 2000 && realservo <2180) {
      int servo2 = realservo;
      servo2 = map(servo2, 2000, 2180, 0, 180);
      myservo2.write(servo2);
      Serial.println("Servo 2 ON");
      delay(10);
    }
    if (realservo >= 3000 && realservo <3180) {
      int servo3 = realservo;
      servo3 = map(servo3, 3000, 3180, 0, 180);
      myservo3.write(servo3);
      Serial.println("Servo 3 ON");
      delay(10);
    }
    if (realservo >= 4000 && realservo <4180) {
      int servo4 = realservo;
      servo4 = map(servo4, 4000, 4180, 0, 180);
      myservo4.write(servo4);
      Serial.println("Servo 4 ON");
      delay(10);
    }
  }   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el puerto serie que abre arduino para hacer la conexión y mediante algunas librerías de C puedes obtener lo que envia el arduino atraves de dicho puerto, esta página te puede proporcionar una buena guía para lo que intentas hacer https://geekytheory.com/como-usar-arduino-y-cplusplus

Comment: Hola Amigo me puedes ayudar Mano, es para un proyecto que tengo que hacer, solo quiero juntar esos codigos, porfavor Mano me puedes ayudar uniendolos solo eso quiero

Comment: Te lo agradecería mucho Amigo!! Porfavor ayudame

Comment: pero a que te refieres con ¿unirlos? quieres pasar el codigo arduino a C++ para que tu clase C haga lo de arduino?

Comment: Unirlos osea juntar Ambos codigos para que pueda ejecutar los dos procesos cuando yo se lo indique. Enverdad te lo agradesería mucho

Comment: Solo quiero unirlos los 2 codigos en 1 solo